# Lubuntu 13.10 Wine Issues

Tags: 13.10, firefox, wine, lubuntu

I have successfully installed Wine to my laptop (it's a dinosaur from 2006 with 1 gig of RAM), and although I only use it because I am so poor that I can't afford a new laptop, I have a very interesting problem whenever I try to use Wine to do anything except the default of running NotePad.exe which comes with Wine:

Everytime I try to run Firefox.exe, Wine fails to execute it, I get an error message like this:
[image]

So as you can see, it's really difficult to troubleshoot this sort of problem (granted I am a noob and basically don't know what I am doing), so I am not sure if it's a Lubuntu issue or if it's a Firefox issue.

I do know, however, that I can run the Firefox that comes with Lubuntu as the default web browser, which you'll see in the picture I am using to post this question.

Thoughts, ideas, comments -- anything is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to run Firefox from inside Wine? It should be installed already, if it isn't you should be able to from Software Centre or by running `sudo apt-get install firefox` :-s

Comment: Of course I have Firefox for Linux, but what I wanted to test out Wine with something and Firefox seemed the easiest.